# Nginx reverse proxy redirection

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using `nginx` as a reverse proxy and when I login in my web interface I am redirected to the proxied URL. I would like to avoid it and always keep the "server_name" as the URL. Is it possible?

This is my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my_app.conf`:

```
server { 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name my-app.net; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/my-app.cer; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/my-app.key; 
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-app.access.log main; 

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://ip_of_the_app:7180/; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    } 
}
```

I connect on `http://my-app.net`, enter login information, I am then redirected to `http://ip_of_the_app:7180` at the same login page, and I have to login again.  Can this double login be avoided?

Comment: tonio94, has your problem been addressed?  if yes, please accept the answer.  if no, please clarify what's missing.

Comment: I just tested it yesterday, it works, proxy_redirect need to be removed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do not set `proxy_redirect` to `off`, that is not doing what you think it is doing.  `proxy_redirect` performs something similar to URL rewriting, for example:

```
location /sales/ { 
    proxy_pass http://ip_of_the_app:7180/; 
    proxy_redirect http://ip_of_the_app:7180/ http://$host/sales/; 
}
```

This allows you to host the `/sales/` path somewhere else.  But even then, the default parameters for `proxy_redirect` do exactly that for you for free.  The default is to redirect the location into whatever is present in `proxy_pass` (and the default parameters are used when you do not set `proxy_redirect` at all, or use `proxy_redirect default;`).

You do not need to set `proxy_redirect`.

---

What you're missing are headers that need to be sent to the app.  The most important of them is `HOST`.  This shall perform the proxying as desired and shall keep the correct URL in the browser.

```
location / { 
    proxy_pass http://ip_of_the_app:7180/; 
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
}
```

Note that the app at `http://ip_of_the_app:7180/` will now receive the request with the `Host: my-app.net` header.

---

You should also consider using a couple more headers:

```
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

This will allow for better logging inside the app at `http://ip_of_the_app:7180/`.  `X-Forwarded-For` giving the IP of the actual client (as opposed to `nginx`s IP) and `X-Forwarded-Proto` to check whether the client connected to the `nginx` through HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
proxy_redirect is not needed but proxy_set_header Referer http://ip_of_the_app:7180/ must be set in order to work properly.

Comment: @tonio94 - Thanks, I updated the answer. Note that the normal usage of the `Referer` is simply `$http_referer` which copies it from the request.  That does not work if the request does not have a Referer header, therefore hardcoding it is a solution in some cases.

Comment: @JonathanKomar - Thank you for that, you are correct, now edited.  Sorry it took me a while to notice your comment.

Comment: @grochmal Thanks, you basically saved my life with this info about: proxy_set_header HOST $host;

Comment: @grochmal I think it should be `X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` this will append the `$remote_addr` IP to a list of possibly multiple forwarding hoops instead of replacing it. `X-Real-IP $remote_addr` is where the previous hoop is supposed to go if I understand this right - see also https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Balance/Reference/httpheaders.htm

Comment: @FelixB. I do not disagree, it would be better to use both X-Real-IP and then place the list in X-Forwarded-For .  Unfortunately, few people/webservers use it that way (at least from my experience), and since the X- headers are just a convention there's no way to enforce anything.  Moreover, if I'm not mistake to pass the full list through to X-Forwarded-For you would need nginx's realip and `real_ip_recursive on;`, which is another can of worms to worry about.  I'd stick to the slightly incorrect but easy to make work solution for now.